# Snap to tangents

Tags: pathfinder, snapping

I am making a logo based on fibonacci circles and I am having quite a difficult time getting these circles to snap perfectly...

I am trying to snap the tangent of the blue circle to the red one.

Also, once all of my shapes are created and I merge the shapes using pathfinder, there's a lot of redundant points, is there a way to clean this up so I have clean geometry?

[image]

[image]